# Can't connect signal to slot of own class

Tags: c++, qt

I need to use a QGraphcisTextItem that can contain links so I've created my own class based on this. Here is the header:

```
class ClickableGraphicsTextItem : public QGraphicsTextItem
{
public:
    ClickableGraphicsTextItem();
    void setHtml(const QString &html);

public slots:
    void linkClicked(QString link);

protected:
    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);

};
```

And the CPP

```
ClickableGraphicsTextItem::ClickableGraphicsTextItem()
{
    connect(this,SIGNAL(linkActivated(QString)),this,SLOT(linkClicked(QString)));
}

void ClickableGraphicsTextItem::setHtml(const QString &html){
    QGraphicsTextItem::setHtml(html);
    qWarning() << "HTML Was set";
}

void ClickableGraphicsTextItem::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event){
    qWarning() << "I was double cliked";
}

void ClickableGraphicsTextItem::linkClicked(QString link){
    qWarning() << "Link" << link << "was clicked";
}
```

Now when I run the program I get this message error in the output console:

```
QObject::connect: No such slot QGraphicsTextItem::linkClicked(QString)
```

Now what I don't understand is why it is attempting to connect to QGraphicsTextItem insted of my ClickableGrapchicsTextItem.

How do I solve this?

Comment: It is a QGraphicsTextItem signal

Comment: Consider using the [New Signal Slot Syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) that'll produce somewhat better compiler errors (vs. boilerplate runtime error messages).

Comment: You don't have `Q_OBJECT` macro in `ClickableGraphicsTextItem` class declaration

Comment: This is weird. I used the new syntax and It didn't throw any errors. It jsut worked. Thank you!!!!

Comment: If the new syntax works, but the old doesn't, then you forgot to generate meta-information (using the MOC). @mvidelgauz's comment tells you, how to get going using the old syntax, where signal-slot connections are resolved at runtime, using the `moc_Xyz` classes, storing the meta-information (similar to standard RTTI, yet more complete).

Comment: sorry guys, can you please educate me what is that "new syntax"? I am now with 5.2.1 if that matters

Comment: @IInspectable Could you please post as an answer so this can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Signals & Slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) in Qt can be implemented in one of two ways:

- Traditionally, using the `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` macros.
- Using the [New Signal Slot Syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax).

When using the `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` macros, signal-slot connections are constructed at runtime. This is performed through string-based lookup. For this to work, the meta-object compiler (MOC) needs to provide additional information, that is made available by adding the [Q_OBJECT](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT) macro to the top of the class declaration.

Using the new signal slot syntax doesn't require the help of the meta-object compiler anymore<sup>1)</sup>. The connection is implemented at compile-time, using Standard C++ features only. String-based lookup has been replaced with function pointers.

---

<sup>1)</sup> *While it is still required to add the `Q_OBJECT` macro for all classes that contain signals or slots, it is sometimes sufficient to derive from `QObject`. This is not contractual, though, and should be seen as an (undocumented) implementation detail.*

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should add Q_OBJECT in your class declaration.

```
class ClickableGraphicsTextItem : public QGraphicsTextItem
{Q_OBJECT
public:
    ...
    ...
    ...

}
```

it should normally work.

Comment: It worked withouth adding it.